# Logical Equivalence for $p \lor q$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I have to prove that

$$p \vee q \equiv (p\wedge q) \vee (\neg p\wedge q) \vee (p\wedge \neg q)$$

Based on the truth table, they are equivalent, but I couldn't figure out how to use logic statements to prove they are equivalent. I have tried many ways but they all go weird.

$(p\wedge q) \vee (\neg p\wedge q) \vee (p\wedge \neg q)$

$\equiv (p\wedge q) \vee ((\neg p\wedge q)\vee p) \wedge ((\neg p\wedge q)\vee \neg q)$

$\equiv (p\wedge q) \vee ((T \wedge (q\vee p)) \wedge (T\wedge \neg(p \wedge q))$

$\equiv (p\wedge q) \vee (q\vee p) \wedge \neg(p \wedge q)$

I couldn't figure out what I'm supposed to from this point. Did I do anything wrong?
Thanks

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi - In fact, the last two brackets don't evaluate to a tautology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the basic logical equivalences listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence), you can easily prove that $p \lor q$ is equivalent to $(p∧q)∨(¬p∧q)∨(p∧¬q)$.

\begin{align}
& \quad \ (p∧q)∨(¬p∧q)∨(p∧¬q) \\
\text{(commutativity)}\quad &\equiv (p \land q) \lor (p \land\lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land q)  \\
\text{(distributivity of $\land$ over $\lor$)} \quad & \equiv (p \land (q \lor \lnot q)) \lor (\lnot p \land q) \\
\text{(negation law)} \quad &\equiv (p \land \top) \lor (\lnot p \land q) \\
\text{(identity law)} \quad &\equiv p \lor (\lnot p \land q) \\
\text{(distributivity of $\lor$ over $\land$)}\quad &\equiv (p \lor \lnot p) \land (p \lor q) \\
\text{(negation law)}\quad &\equiv \top \land (p \lor q) \\
\text{(identity law)}\quad &\equiv p \lor q
\end{align}
where $\top$ stands for a *tautology*, i.e. a formula that is always true.
In the first two lines, the use of the associativity law is left implicit.

Answer (score 1):

To prove $p \vee q \equiv (p\wedge q) \vee (\neg p\wedge q) \vee (p\wedge \neg q)$, let's start from RHS as follows.

$(p\wedge q) \vee (\neg p\wedge q) \vee (p\wedge \neg q)$

$\equiv q \wedge (p\vee \neg p) \vee (p\wedge \neg q)$

$\equiv (q \wedge \text{T}) \vee (p\wedge \neg q)$

$\equiv q \vee (p\wedge \neg q)$

$\equiv (q \vee p)\wedge(q\vee \neg q)$

$\equiv (q \vee p)\wedge \text{T}$

$\equiv (q \vee p)$

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

For better readability I use $+$ for "or", $\cdot$ for "and" and $()'$ for negation.

So, you have
\begin{eqnarray*} pq + p'q+pq'
& = & (p+p')q+pq' \\
& = & q + pq' \\
& \stackrel{DeMorgan}{=} & (q'(p'+q))' \\
& \stackrel{qq' = F}{=} & (q'p')' \\
& = & p+q
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Appreciate the help. It's different from what I learned but it seems easier to read. Maybe it would be faster if q+pq' = (q+p)(q+q') = p+q.

Comment: @user665125 You are welcome. And yes, the way without DeMorgan you suggest in your comment is also quite quick and elegant. :-)